# Prove thant if $a/b + c/d \in \mathbb Z, (a:b)= 1, (c:d) =1 $ then $|b|=|d|$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Be $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z, b \ne  0, d \ne  0.$ Prove that if $a/b + c/d \in \mathbb Z, (a:b)= 1, (c:d) =1 $ then $|b|=|d|$

Comment: What is $(a:b)=1$? Is this $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: yes, sorry, the author I work whit, defined it like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write
$$\frac a b+\frac c d=n\iff ad+bc=bdn$$
then we have $b|(bdn-bc)$ so $b|ad$ and since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $b|d$ using [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

By similar method we prove that $d|b$ and we conclude that $b$ and $d$ are associate.